# Combine two MySQL SELECT queries from single table

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT 
(111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS({$lat})) 
* COS(RADIANS(lat)) 
* COS(RADIANS({$lon}) - RADIANS(lon)) + SIN(RADIANS({$lat})) 
* SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) AS distance, 
(`f1` + `f2` + `f5` + `f6`) AS sum 
FROM `shops` 
WHERE distance <= 25
```

where first part returns shops within certain distance and second part returns sum of given fields in the same row of the same table.

Both parts work separately but do not return results when combined.

Please tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: Count the number of fields you have distance <= 25

Comment: Just replace the keyword **`WHERE`** with **`HAVING`**. That should fix one problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use alias in where

```
SELECT 
(111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS({$lat})) 
* COS(RADIANS(lat)) 
* COS(RADIANS({$lon}) - RADIANS(lon)) + SIN(RADIANS({$lat})) 
* SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) AS distance, 
(f1 + f2 + f5 + f6) AS sum 
FROM shops 
WHERE   (111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS({$lat})) 
* COS(RADIANS(lat)) 
* COS(RADIANS({$lon}) - RADIANS(lon)) + SIN(RADIANS({$lat})) 
* SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) <= 25
```

Comment: `SUM` is *not* a MySQL Reserved Word.  (It's fine to enclose identifiers in backticks. And it's true that `SUM()` is an aggregate function. I think it's good practice to avoid using keywords and function names as identifiers.) But `SUM` is not a reserved word in MySQL. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @spencer7593   .right  .. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: So this means there was a column in the table named `distance` and it was using that value for the comparison? Or is there another reason?

Comment: @shawnt00  the word distance is an alias for the formula ... if the OP use where is not possibile use alias for filtering ..so he must use the fukll formula as a column ....the OP   could use having that work on result of the querys .. hope is clear ..

Comment: I just don't know the limitations of using the aliases on MySQL. So I don't understand why it isn't equivalent or why it didn't at least fail to execute in the first place.

Comment: @shawnt00 the use of alias in a query depend of their "scope"  .. a select alias  is not  available for where  .. because the where condition is evaluated before of the select .. and alias in select is instead visible in group by or having clause .. because these action are performed on the result of select .. then in this case the query was right if use having instead of where  (using the alias "distance" ..

Comment: OP said "Both parts work separately..." How do you interpret that?

Comment: @shawnt00   . i don't  .. know  .. this question should be for the OP .. could be he don't use alias .. or the queries are different respect the query shiowed ..  ..

Comment: Ok. I thought you jumped on the solution pretty fast and that you had some insight.

Comment: @shawnt00   . i jumped to the solution  ..fast .. because the use of the alias in where condition  ..is know error  .. clearly visible .. in the OP question ..